# working with extra nested POJOs trees

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there anything smart I can do with very complicated POJOs tree in my template?

e.g.

```
<div
     important-attr="{{item.another_sub_item_three.lets_go_a_little_dipper.property}} "
     another-important-attr="{{ item.another_sub_item_three.just_one_more.another-property }}"
>
</div>
```

Please note I have no control over the data-structure, it comes from legacy API.

Using ng-repeat might be a solution, but this doe snot feel right, especially this is not a collection, it's just an item.

```
<div
    ng-repeat="prop in item.another_sub_item_three.lets_go_a_little_dipper"
    important-attr="{{prop.property}}"
    another-important-attr="{{prop.another-property}}"
>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to add tags in title.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `$http` to interface with your legacy API, you could use the `transformResponse` property to change the response into a more manageable one.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '...',
  transformResponse: function(data) {
    /* transform data then */
    return data
  }
})
```

If you're not using `$http`, there's probably another logical place in your code where you can transform the API response before it is consumed by your template.

Comment: A do another `ng-repeat` higher in the tree - which gives me the `item`, but then there is another tree monster inside each `item`